# How to access xpath parsing using Kotlin JS

Tags: kotlin, xpath

I'm experimenting with Kotlin JS before using it in a project.
I'd like to parse a HTML doc using `xpath` specifications that the user is prompted to upload to the site.

```
    import kotlinx.browser.document

    val h1 = document.asDynamic().evaluate("//h1", getDocument())
    println("xpath h1=${h1}")
    return h1
```

In a browser console window, the `println` displays `xpath h1=[object XPathResult]`

Two questions:

1. is `…evaluate() a good approach for XPath parsing in Kotlin JS`?
2. where is `XPathResult` defined in Kotlin JS? Intellij doesn't offer to add an appropriate import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `asDynamic().evaluate` is the common approach; however, there are custom wrappers [[1]](https://github.com/cy6erGn0m/kotlin.xpath) to make things more type-safe
2. As stated in ['Use JavaScript code from Kotlin'](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/js-interop.html)

> You can freely talk to JavaScript from Kotlin via dynamic types. If
> you want to use the full power of the Kotlin type system, you can
> create external declarations for JavaScript libraries which will be
> understood by the Kotlin compiler and the surrounding tooling. ...

> To tell Kotlin that a certain declaration is written in pure
> JavaScript, you should mark it with the external modifier.

[Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75300493/8291949) of how this could look like when you import [XPathResult](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XPathResult) as an external object in kotlin.